# Reading a txt file and saving individual columns as lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to read a .txt file and save the data in each column as a list. each column in the file contains a variable which I will later on use to plot a graph. I have tried looking up the best method to do this and most answers recommend opening the file, reading it, and then either splitting or saving the columns as a list. The data in the .txt is as follows -

```
0   1.644231726
0.00025 1.651333945
0.0005  1.669593478
0.00075 1.695214575
0.001   1.725409504
```

the delimiter is a space `''` or a tab `'\t'` . I have used the following code to try and append the columns to my variables -

```
import csv

with open('./rvt.txt') as file:
    readfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    time = []
    rim = []
    for line in readfile:
        t = line[0]
        r = line[1]
        time.append(t)
        rim.append(r)

print(time, rim)
```

However, when I try to print the lists, time and rim, using `print(time, rim)`, I get the following error message -

```
r = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am, however, able to print only the 'time' if I comment out the `r=line[1]` and `rim.append(r)` parts. How do I approach this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should use pandas?

Comment: Most probably one of your lines in the text file does not contain two values for `time` and `rim`, thus `line[1]` does not exist and this Error pops up. You could also print the line number to find out which line produces this error and inspect the file there. Anyhow, `pandas` seems to be a better choice as it will be more fault tolerant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('./rvt.txt', sep='\t'), header=[a list with your column names])
```

Then you can use list(your_column) to work with your columns as lists

Comment: Great, please accept (and upvote maybe) the answer, so that question will leave from 'unanswered' queue. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is with the delimiter.** The *dataset* contain multiple space ' '.

When you use `'\t'` and
print `line` you can see it's not separating the line with the delimiter.

eg:

```
['0   1.644231726']
['0.00025 1.651333945']
['0.0005  1.669593478']
['0.00075 1.695214575']
['0.001   1.725409504']
```

To get the desired result you can use   (space) as delimiter and `filter` the empty values:

```
readfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter=" ")
time, rim = [], []
for line in readfile:
    line = list(filter(lambda x: len(x), line))
    t = line[0]
    r = line[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do this:

```
import csv

with open('./rvt.txt') as file:
    readfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter=” ”)
    time = []
    rim = []
    for line in readfile:
        t = line[0]
        r = line[1]
        time.append(t)
        rim.append(r)
print(time, rim)
```

Comment: This will give incorrect value in r. As I have explained in my answer, the space are inconsistent between the rows, the value `r = line[1]  # will get " " instead of actual value`